# Django : Custom save method with queryset

Tags: python, django, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to create a `custom save method` in my model and I would like to get your help in order to improve this one.

I'm generating a `unique code` based on some variables in my `form`. I generate the code and I make a research before to save it. If another document already gets this code, I generate another one, else I save the object.

This is my `save()` method in my models.py file :

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    import random
    self.code = f"{self.publication.pub_id}-{self.language.upper()}-{self.format.upper()}-{random.randint(1,10001)}"
    document = Document.objects.filter(code=self.code)
    if document:
        self.code = f"{self.publication.pub_id}-{self.language.upper()}-{self.format.upper()}-{random.randint(1,10001)}"
    super(Document, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I think it could me improved, by `while` instead of `if` condition.

What do you think about it ?

Thank you

Comment: How can a `while` loop be more efficient than a single `if` condition?

Comment: Because if `self.code` in the `if` statement already exists in my database ? I need to loop until I get a unique `self.code`. Maybe it's not a `while` loop and I have to improve my `if` ?

Comment: Okay that isn't `efficient` code. That is `correct` code. What you're doing here is incorrect actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a `while` to check if my code is unique, it's quite self explanary and i modified for your code purpose :

```
def _get_unique_code(self):
    """

    To be used only once in the save method. It creates the unique code.

    """
    import random
    self.code = f"{self.publication.pub_id}-{self.language.upper()}-{self.format.upper()}-{random.randint(1,10001)}"
    while Document.objects.filter(code=self.code).exists():
        self.code = f"{self.publication.pub_id}-{self.language.upper()}-{self.format.upper()}-{random.randint(1,10001)}"
    return self.code

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.code:
        self.code = self._get_unique_code()
    super(Document, self).save()
```

Comment: Yes to my mind it works fine ! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming save() method is of model Document and I think `self.code` will always be unique(because of pub_id and randomint) so `if/while` looks unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 0):

The probability at which you'll get matching codes already existing in your database would be one in a million to say the least.

Having said that, this is the `while` you might have been looking for.

```
import random
def get_code(self):
    self.code = f"{self.publication.pub_id}-{self.language.upper()}-{self.format.upper()}-{random.randint(1,10001)}"
    while Document.objects.filter(code=self.code).exists():
        self.code = f"{self.publication.pub_id}-{self.language.upper()}-{self.format.upper()}-{random.randint(1,10001)}"
    return self.code

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.code:
        self.code = self.get_code()
    super(Document, self).save()
```